# CSS Menu - Display the active pages items submenu

Tags: css, menu

I have a typical CSS top navigation which displays a submenu when you roll over the different parent menu items. How can I change the code to keep the active submenu displayed. So if you were on the page for that parent menu item, or one of its children, it would keep that submenu displayed unless you hovered over another parent menu item.

Here is a jsfiddle link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cgzUm/

The code itself:

```html
<div id="topbar">
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="elements">
        <ul>
            <li id="menua"><a href="#">Menu A</a>
                <div class="subnavbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu A1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu A2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu A3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="menub"><a href="#">Menu B</a>
                <div class="subnavbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu B1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu B2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu B3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="menuc"><a href="#">Menu C</a>
                <div class="subnavbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu C1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu C2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu C3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="menud"><a href="#">Menu D</a>
                <div class="subnavbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu D1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu D2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu D3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```css
#navbar { position: relative; width: 990px; height: 40px; z-index: 12; margin: 0px auto; }
#navbar .elements { display: inline; float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; }
#navbar .elements > ul { clear: left; display: inline; float: left; position: relative; left: 50%; height: 40px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; }
#navbar .elements > ul > li { display: inline; float: left; position: relative; right: 50%; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px; height: 25px; font-size: 14px; }
#navbar .elements > ul > li > a { display: block; color: #002B55; overflow: hidden; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; padding: 0px 25px; margin: 0px; }
#navbar .elements a:hover, #navbar .elements li a.selected { color: #0073AE; }
#navbar .elements > ul > li:hover .subnavbar { display:block; }
#navbar .elements > ul > li > a:active .subnavbar { display:block; }
#navbar .subnavbar { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 27px; top: 40px; left: 0px; background-color: #FFF; border-top: 1px solid #2B2B2B; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 13; display: none; }
#navbar .subnavbar.over { display: block; padding-bottom: 7px; }
#navbar .subnavbar ul { height: 27px; z-index: 5; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; }
#navbar .subnavbar ul li { display: inline; text-transform: uppercase; }
#navbar .subnavbar ul li a { text-decoration: none; line-height: 27px; font-size: 12px; padding: 7px 8px 7px 9px; color: #002B55; }
#navbar .subnavbar ul li a:hover { color: #0073AE; }
#navbar .subnavbar ul li a.selected { color: #0073AE; }
#navbar .selected .subnavbar { z-index: 12; }
#navbar ul > li.selected div.subnavbar { display: block; }
#navbar .elements > ul > li { padding-bottom: 6px; }
```

Comment: You would need to add a class active to the active menu item on the server side. Then, add the CSS for keeping that menu open.

Answer (score 1):

First, add class="active" on the li which is the active menu item, like this:

```
<li id="about" class="active"><a href="/wordpress/about">About</a>
```

Then add this line of CSS:

```css
#navbar .elements > ul > li.active .subnavbar { display:block; z-index:1; }
```

and update the z-index on this one:

```css
#navbar .elements > ul > li:hover .subnavbar { display:block; z-index:2;}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgzUm/4/

Comment: oops, wait - I just realized that this has problems if a later li is made the active - then it hides the first subnav under it.  I think something needs to be updated to make sure all other subnavs are hidden while one is being rolled over...  let me look.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this through pseudo selectors instead? Like a:active?

Comment: you mean like a:active?  a:active describes the state of a link when it is in the process of being clicked; like when you click down on it but don't yet release the mouse button.  It has nothing to do with an active page like you are looking for.

Comment: adding z-indexes fixes the problem in my first comment; will update my answer accordingly.